# Prevent an infinite loop on window resize

Tags: jquery

By chaining the `resize` function onto an initialize slider object, I am able to make a [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) element resize nicely in a responsive grid. By running it whenever the window resizes, I can get a pretty sharp responsive slideshow:

```
var timer;
$(window).resize(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( function(){
        console.log('resize');
        $('#slider-2').resize();
    }, 500)
});
```

However, placing `$('#slider-2').resize();` inside the `$(window).resize`' anonymous function actually causes an infinite loop; [click here, open the console and resize the window to see.](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/196/).

How can I prevent this loop? The window isn't resizing, so I didn't think this would happen. Can I exclude `$('#slider-2')` in the selector or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, events bubble up the DOM. When you resize the window, you trigger a resize event on the slider which then makes it way up the DOM back to the window object and triggers another resize. You need to make sure the resize event handler on #slider-2 stops propagation.

Check out this code:

```
$('#slider-2').on('resize',function(event){
event.stopPropagation()
});

var timer;
$(window).resize(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( function(){
        console.log('resize');
        $('#slider-2').resize();
    }, 500)
});
```